# Cannot get headlines content while scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am new to scraping but I have tried every method to solve this problem but not getting the desired results. I want to scrape this site https://www.accesswire.com/newsroom/ and I want to scrape all the headlines, headlines show up when I inspect them in browser but after scraping with bs4 or selenium, I do not get the full page-Source code and also don't get the headlines as well.

I have tried `time.sleep(10)` but that is also not working out for me. I used selenium to get the page but that also wouldn't work for me as well.
div.column-15 w-col w-col-9
this is the class, div where headlines reside

```
ua     = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}
url = "https://www.accesswire.com/newsroom/"
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
time.sleep(12)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(12)
headline_Div = soup.find("div",{"class":"column-15 w-col w-col-9"})
print(headline_Div)
```

I just want to get all the headlines and headlines links on this page
or at least a full page-source should be displayed so that I can manipulate it by myself.

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: The site appears to load asynchronously and dynamically, so requests and BS4 won;t be able to get the page elements. Please include what you've tried in selenium, as that will likely be a better route to take

Comment: i get page source of the site but not the headlines. which is something i want to scrap

Comment: here is the selenium code

Comment: ```import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/MUNTAZIR/Downloads/Compressed/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(5)
site_url = "https://www.accesswire.com/newsroom/"
time.sleep(5)
print(site_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: it output this result

Comment: https://www.accesswire.com/newsroom/
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pull and parse is not working is because the content is dynamic, you will need selenium for the actual browser to generate the content for you

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.accesswire.com/newsroom/')
headline_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.headlinelink')
headlines = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in headline_links]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need selenium. Just use the more efficient requests and the API which the page uses

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.accesswire.com/api/newsroom.ashx')
p = re.compile(r" \$\('#newslist'\)\.after\('(.*)\);")
html = p.findall(r.text)[0]
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
headlines = [(item.text, item['href']) for item in soup.select('a.headlinelink')]
print(headlines)
```

---

Regex explanation:

[image]

Try regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/A4fDOT/1)

Comment: can you please suggest any good tutorial/docs on  how to improve the speed of scraping  @dalvenjia

Comment: use an API as shown above should be first choice. Other than that a lot will be about choosing the right tool for the job, the optimal selector method/selector path, correct and optimal use of waits where required; code structure...... I am sure you can google for these. I mostly pick up by Google. I am new to python so would look to experienced pythonistas to see how they structure their code and what syntax they use. The above I would say is pretty efficient.

Comment: Another awesome approach yet again @QHarr.